# conditional display of table row based on settings

Tags: jquery, toggle

So I have a number of checkboxes that toggle table rows show/hide based on the classes each row has.

HTML:

```
GENDER: 
<label><input name="male" type="checkbox" id="male" checked> Male</label>
<label><input name="female" type="checkbox" id="female" checked> Female</label>
<br>
Subject: 
<label><input name="form" type="checkbox" id="form" checked> Form</label>
<label><input name="english" type="checkbox" id="english" checked> English</label>
<label><input name="maths" type="checkbox" id="maths" checked> Maths</label>
<label><input name="science" type="checkbox" id="science" checked> Science</label>
<br>
Competence: 
<label><input name="slow" type="checkbox" id="slow" checked> Slow</label>
<label><input name="normal" type="checkbox" id="normal" checked> Normal</label>
<label><input name="fast" type="checkbox" id="fast" checked> Fast</label>

<table>
  <tr class="row male form slow"><td>content</td></tr>
  <tr class="female english normal"><td>content</td></tr>
  <tr class="female maths normal"><td>content</td></tr>
  <tr class="male science fast"><td>content</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#male" ).change(function() {
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".male" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".male" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#female" ).change(function() {
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".female" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".female" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#form" ).change(function() {
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".form" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".form" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#english" ).change(function() {
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".english" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".english" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#maths" ).change(function() {
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".maths" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".maths" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#science" ).change(function() {
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".science" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".science" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#slow" ).change(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    if ( $input.prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".slow" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $input.prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".slow" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#normal" ).change(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    if ( $input.prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".normal" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $input.prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".normal" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
$( "#fast" ).change(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    if ( $input.prop( "checked" ) == true ) $( ".fast" ).fadeIn();
    if ( $input.prop( "checked" ) == false ) $( ".fast" ).fadeOut();
}).change();
```

I have it all working fine except for one thing: if I toggle the 'male' off, then toggle the 'fast' off and then toggle 'male' back on the middle row displays when it shouldn't, because it is also toggled off for 'fast'. I understand why it does this but I can't get it to stay hidden until both toggles are on.

I've tried getting row ids and working from there but keep falling short.

Any wisdom would be great because I'm stuck.

Comment: Thanks @ devlin-carnate and @ kad. Given the way you have both answered the question I think I need to add that there are more checkboxes! I didn't think to mention them all because I didn't suspect the answers you've given. But there are relationships between them. I'll amend the code above to show the checkboxes. The jquery follows the same pattern for all of them. Sorry if this messes things about...just didn't think!

Answer (score 1):

Since both checkboxes are related, you need to handle the case of single class separately from a row having both classes:

Here is a working fiddle

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){


  var male = $("#male").is(":checked");
  var fast = $("#fast").is(":checked");
  
  if(male)
  {
      $( ".male" ).not('.fast').fadeIn();
  }
  else
  {
       $( ".male" ).not('.fast').fadeOut();
  }
  
  if(fast)
  {
      $( ".fast" ).not('.male').fadeIn();
  }
  else
  {
       $( ".fast" ).not('.male').fadeOut();
  }
  
  if(fast && male)
  {
       $( ".male.fast" ).fadeIn();
  }
  else
  {
      $( ".male.fast" ).fadeOut();
  }
  
});
```

```css
.male
{
  color:red;
  }

.fast
{
  color:blue;
  }


.male.fast
{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input name="male" type="checkbox" id="male" checked> Male</label>
<label><input name="fast" type="checkbox" id="fast" checked> Fast</label>

<table>
  <tr class="male"><td>content1 male</td></tr>
  <tr class="fast"><td>content2 fast</td></tr>
  <tr class="male fast"><td>content3 male fast</td></tr>
  <tr class="male"><td>content4 male</td></tr>
  <tr class="fast"><td>content5 fast</td></tr>
  <tr class="male fast"><td>content6 male fast</td></tr>
  <tr class="fast"><td>content7 fast</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @kad - not sure what you mean by related but this is a good solution. Have you seen my edit above?

Answer (score 1):

You need to omit the fast class when Male is checked.

```
( ".male:not(.fast)" ).fadeIn();
```

But you also need to check and see if the Fast checkbox is checked before omitting the fast class.

```
$("#male").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    if ($("#fast").prop("checked")) {
      $(".male").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(".male:not(.fast)").fadeIn();
    }
  }
  if (!$(this).prop("checked")) $(".male").fadeOut();
}).change();
$("#fast").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    if ($("#male").prop("checked")) {
      $(".fast").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(".fast:not(.male)").fadeIn();
    }
  }
  if (!$(this).prop("checked")) $(".fast").fadeOut();
}).change();
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h5otqeaL/1/).

Comment: Thanks @devlin-carnate - I like this solution very much. Have you seen my update above?

Comment: @StephenWeatherill - you can apply the same logic to your other groups.  For every checkbox that has an association with another checkbox, you'll need to test the associated checkbox checked property.  In the example I gave, Fast is associated with Male, so in both functions, I test to see the status of the associated checkbox and exclude the class of the associated checkbox if it's not checked.

Comment: For example, if you have 3 checkboxes associated with each other (let's call them A, B and C), you need to test the checked status of B & C any time A is clicked.  You can chain the ":not" exclusion if your test shows the other two checkboxes are not checked, like so:  `$(".A:not(.B):not(.C)").fadeIn()`.  You should work with what I've given you and understand it, and then you will be able to expand on it.  I'm not going to give you the full code because that's not going to help you in the long run ;)

Comment: Thanks @devlin-carnate for your response - that's really helpful...and I'm glad you didn't 'help' too much. ;) I found the chaining especially insightful - didn't know you could do this so simply. Many thanks.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this but not getting to the solution! If you view my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h5otqeaL/6/ you will see that I can only get it to partially work. If I use && it breaks down and if I use || it doesn't keep rows switched off as I want it to. I can understand why on both counts but can't for the life of me figure out what else to try! Any pointers you can offer...please? :)